# WPF Designer Error

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-forms-designer, unhandled-exception

Every time i edit a control or Item using the designer, or code.. The designer gives an exception, yet if i reload the designer it shows the view again, in design view. Then when editing it will, show the same error once again. .. And i can't figure out why it does it at all! Becoming a bit frustrating to say the least. Link below shows the error i receive
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d49ahlcf33efegr/wpfDesigner.PNG

Comment: Please show some code, I had such exceptions when binding to properties that have not been initialized.

Comment: I agree with webber2k6 you might have some code behind stuff that is triggered in design mode. Please note that when you open a view in the Designer it's c'tor is executed. I'd recomment to comment everything except InitializeComponent() and check if it works then ...

Comment: It works fine on a another pc i sometimes use, yet as soon as i use it on another pc i begin to experience isseus.. Could it be something to do with a service pack update etc?